# Why do I see a "400 (Bad Request)" in my developer console when sign-in to Firebase Authentication fails?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I'm using the method signInWithEmailAndPassword to validate a user in my angular based application, I wrote this code:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
    function(authData) {
      //user was validated
        console.log(authData);
    },
    function(error) {
        if(error){
            // Handle Errors
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
              alert('Wrong password.');
            } else {
              alert(errorMessage);
            }      
      }
    });
```

When I run this code with a valid user and password it works well, no errors in the console, but when I set an invalid user it throws a Bad Request in the console, and then it returns the corresponding error which is user inexistent. So it seems the validation is working fine but I wonder what this bad request means or what I'm missing in the code. This is the bad request message

> POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=AIzaSyDDCVDWgy9LGYLWmMPQjPZ49RbDkWjWVTk 400 (Bad Request)  firebase.js:107

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This HTTP request is how Firebase Authentication verifies the user credentials. The SDK/client then turns it into the error with an `errorCode` and `errorMessage` that you handle.

You can see that if you look in the body of the response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND"
 }
}
```

Comment: Great, so those bad request in console are just informative and not an error from my side