# Firebase: return caught error from signInWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase with Email+Password auth provider. Correct credentials case works as expected. My problem is that if credentials are wrong, error is caught, but I don't know how to pass this information back.

I am connecting dispatch from redux store with `mapDispatchToProps`.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  startLogin: (email, password) => dispatch(startLogin(email, password))
});
```

Then I just call this action with credentials from my component and if undefined was returned (error thrown), I set errors.

```
startLogin(email, password).then((data) => {
  if (!data) {
    setErrors({ login: 'Wrong credentials' });
  }
});
```

My action look like this.

```
export const startLogin = (email, password) => {
  return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

This works, but console shows POST 400 error which I would like to avoid.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't avoid getting that error logged into the console, because:

1) [This HTTP request is how Firebase Authentication verifies the user credentials.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581590/why-do-i-see-a-400-bad-request-in-my-developer-console-when-sign-in-to-fireb) So the library actually POSTs the credentials, and if they're not good then the server responds with that status.

And then...

2) [Your browser decides to log bad requests to the log.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113286/prevent-http-errors-from-being-logged-in-browser-console) Firebase wraps up the error for you to handle, but by this time the browser has already logged it into the console, something you can't prevent.

If you had control over the API you might like to always return a 200 code with some custom error handling logic, but in this case you should consider making peace with it :)